# Representing signals propagated through a directed graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, signals, computer-science, simulation

This is going to be sort of long and probably more computer-science related than anything language specific (though I need to be using Java). You have been warned.

I'm trying to model the propagation of electrical signals on parallel wires to simulate basic computer hardware. Each path has various elements on it causing for delay, magnification, and other such transformations of my original signals.

Here is an image I just made:

[image: A simple example of what I'm trying to represent]

Thankfully I'm not trying to represent any complex signals - just 0's and 1's. In the example there are 4 inputs; say the user selects them to be 1011. Then I need to send forward these inputs through the wires and into the gates, with the gates producing the appropriate output and continuing to propagate the signals.

The issue is timing. I assign every wire and every gate a time delay. For example, if the top left-most wire has a time delay of 0.5, then it takes 0.5 units of time for the first gate to receive the input. I've draw every gate as multi-input, so the following might happen (consider an AND gate): input1 arrives in 1.1 units of time, and is high; the output is still zero. But then input2 (also high) had a 1.3 unit delay to get there, so 0.2 units later the output will be recalculated to turn high. In fact each gate itself will have a delay, so say the AND gate takes 0.5 units to compute; the final high output will take (1.3 + 0.5) = 1.8 units to turn high.

The current programming model I have is this: wires and gates are objects which can connect to each other and send a signal forward. For example wireA_input is connected to an actual input and wireA_output is connected to a gate. So the input signal comes in (changes from its previous value), and that action should call the send_signal(wireA, input). This function changes the value on wireA to the input value after wireA_delay. Then wireA does send_signal(gateA, wireA_value), which causes the gate to recompute its value and then send it forward to the next object after gateA_delay, etc.

But I need propagate signals in parallel - I can't just focus on one serial path! So my idea was to make multiple threads for every input. At most I'm thinking I'll need 32 input signals, so 32 threads. I would love to schedule them in a round-robin order for equality, I'm not sure if I can do this with the JVM. Either way they'll all get the same priority.

Now the ith input thread does what I describe above - it propagates down the signal. But what happens when a path branches out to many paths?

It's important to note that gates can have multiple "fan outs", i.e. links to other places from their output. That value will typically be 4 at most. So after gateA gets set, it knows that it needs to call send_signal(wireB->E, gateA_value) 4 times, one for each of its fanouts.

Ideally I would like to not branch out to different threads, that would really suck and probably be impossible for larger designs, but hey maybe the whole notion of threads was unnecessary in the first place. I don't need to simulate at ridiculous speeds, just enough to appear responsive to the human user.

So back to my possible implementation - an input thread is propagating along a serial path until BAM - it branches out to 4 different paths. Here's my idea: let the same thread have the 4 paths, for now. Each path has its own delay (ex: 1.4, 2.2, 3.6,  1.1). Multiply each delay by 100, and loop through N iterations where N corresponds to the max delay (in this case: 360). At various checkpoints in the loop corresponding to the other delays (i = 110, 140, 220), propagate those various paths one step forward (i.e. send the signal to the immediate next object on the path). But then we need to add this object to the looping list and count for the appropriate # of iterations again before we propagate further down that particular path.

When the 1 to 4 path has all 4 paths branching out to 4 more paths (and so on and so on), then I'm sort of screwed; but maybe this approach is enough to get me started?

Again I may be coming at this problem from the complete wrong direction, and I'm willing to step back and rethink it. Hence why I'm asking you guys.

Thank you very much for any input at all, or even reading this damn thing. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

If all of your delays are non-negative (safe assumption) and deterministic (reasonably safe assumption) then every time you have an event, you automatically know what events it triggers *and when they happen*.

Why not just use a priority queue for events and handle them as they happen?  When something happens, calculate the times of all the resulting events and add them to the queue; then grab the next event from the queue and handle it.

Comment: +1. This was going to be my suggestion but you beat me to it.  (Although this approach is tricky to parallelize...)

Comment: True, but my goal was to avoid the parallelization altogether, which is in this case not necessary.  (Just nobody ask me how to get this to work with transient time domain effects, because I suspect that is a whole different technique with lots of differential equations.)

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer this sounds pretty good for those assumptions. Just to recap what I really need to do is capture an input changing (the "event") and propagate throughout the graph its affects on all the nodes and wires in the system. Because I might have a small data bus or something, multiple input events could happen simultaneous, hence why I wanted to make threads for each event and compute the effects in parallel to try and be more realistic. But then again just multiplexing through a queue of events should in the end give me the same result. Thanks